# get value in table manytomany django

Tags: django, get

hi I am trying to get the same value in a `many to many` tables but I don't know how can I achieve that

here is my model:

```
class Raza(models.Model):
     Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
     Origen = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     Altura = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Peso = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Esperanza_vida = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     Actividad_fisica = models.CharField(max_length=45)
     Recomendaciones = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     Clasificacion_FCI = models.ForeignKey(Clasificacion_FCI,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     Tipo_pelo = models.ManyToManyField(Tipo_pelo,blank=True)
     Caracteristicas_fisicas = models.ManyToManyField(Caracteristicas_fisicas,blank=True)
     Caracter = models.ManyToManyField(Caracter,blank=True)
     Ideal = models.ManyToManyField(Ideal,blank=True)
     Tamanio = models.ForeignKey(Tamanio,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     User = models.ManyToManyField(User,blank=True)
```

I am using the User model that's provided by Django

I have no idea how can I do that

I want do something like that

```
table user 
id_usuario = 1
name = "Juan"

table raza
id_raza = 1 
name = "pitbull"

table user_raza
id_user_raza = 1
id_user = 1
id_raza = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please write class attributes with small letters in python.

to your question:

```
raza = Raza.objects.get(id=1)

tipo_pelos = raza.tipo_pelo.all()
for tp in tipo_pelos:
    print(tp.id)
...
...
```

Django has [wonderful documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) for this. Have fun.